# check dropdown option selected in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a form in my page that is mapped to a JSON via angular model, unfortunately when the page is loaded I have no way of knowing if the select element is going to be null, zero or have a value.

What is the easier way for me to check the value of the select when the page loads so I can determine the next action.

As you can see in the fiddle, I have a "State" dropdown that on page load I need to check and see if any of the options are marked as selected, if so, I need to extract the one that is selected and do an ajax call with it.

I thought on leveraging $pristine but that is only for inputs, I don't think it applies to select elements, correct?

For illustration purposes, I copied a piece of the json onto the fiddle so you can see what I see when i load the page.

the second question is similar, but for input elements, where the json could come back (based on preloaded data) with null, zero or some value in it. So how do I check on page load for this field and see what the value is?

The json is passed to me by the server after the backend calls the database so I have no idea what type of values are coming in.

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jorgecas99/S8gMr/

Comment: Can you provide more details as to what you are trying to achieve? A fiddle would be great. Is this html generated on the server side? How is the form mapped to the json? I cant see a ng-model on the inputs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is still not quite clear from your fiddle and question what you need but I had a play with your fiddle and produced something that does what I would expect it to do :-)

http://jsfiddle.net/Td2NZ/

Answer (score 0):

Checked Dropdownlist with angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/nimeshvaghasiya/f9fGD/`enter code here`